# Arduino Button Trouble

Tags: arduino

I am just trying to make it so the light turns on when my button state is high. what am I doing wrong??? I keep getting it randomly turning on and off. Thank you in advance.

```
const int buttonPin = 2; 
const int ledPin =  13;
int buttonState = 0;
boolean curstat = LOW;
boolean lasstat = LOW;
boolean ledState = LOW;


void loop(){
 curstat = digitalRead(buttonPin);

if (curstat == HIGH && lasstat == LOW){
 Serial.println("pressed");
delay(1);
bucount = bucount + 1;
Serial.println(bucount);
myservo.write(180);
delay(1);
 digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 
  delay(1);


}
else if(curstat == LOW && lasstat == HIGH){ 
  Serial.println("relased");
  delay(1);
  myservo.write(89);
  delay(1);
   digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 
  delay(1);
}
else if(curstat == LOW && lasstat == LOW){
  Serial.println("nothing has happened");
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
delay(1);
myservo.write(90);
  delay(1);

}
}
```

Comment: Consider cutting down the amount of code required to exhibit your problem. We don't need to care about the servo or all those delays.

Comment: Did you declare buttonPin as input  (pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT) - in setup) ?;
Did you use pull-up resistor (internal/external) ?pinMode(inputPin, INPUT); Nice tutorial is on: http://www.roguescience.org/wordpress/building-a-midi-out-controller/part-3-add-a-switch/exercise-6/

Answer (score 0):

first of all you'll need to declare input and output in setup:

```
void setup(){
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT)
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT)
}
```

the other important thing is that you read curstat, but you never change lasstat, so Arduino will never understand previous state, consider adding this code:

```
if (curstat == HIGH && lasstat == LOW){
    Serial.println("pressed");
    delay(1);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 
    delay(1);
    lasstat = HIGH;
}
```

In this way you'll enter in if statement only once, even if you'll keep your button pressed too long. Don't forget to change lasstat also in other if statements.

Ciao!